Handling Fix_List and Provider Mode with Connection Pooling and Failover
I am working on integrating a Java application with a GridDB server using the GridDB JDBC driver, and I want to optimize the configuration for Fix_List and Provider modes. While I understand the basics of setting up these modes, I am encountering challenges when implementing advanced features such as connection pooling and failover handling.
Fix_List Mode Configuration:
jdbc:griddb://<Node1_IP>:<Node1_Port>,<Node2_IP>:<Node2_Port>/<ClusterName>


Provider Mode Configuration:
jdbc:griddb://<ProviderAddress>:<ProviderPort>


I expect this mode to dynamically manage node information, but it seems inconsistent when nodes are added or removed.
Specific Questions:

Is there a way to preconfigure failover options or adjust timeout settings for Fix_List mode to handle node failures more gracefully?
Are there best practices for optimizing Provider mode to handle dynamic node scaling without restarting the application?
What are the recommended parameters for configuring connection pooling with GridDB JDBC to balance performance and reliability?
Are there diagnostic tools or logs in GridDB to better understand node failovers or connection issues?

